# Using AngularJS: I have four colored squares on my webpage. When I click on one of them, I want the other three to disappear

Tags: angularjs

I have tried using a simple ng-hide or ng-show directive, but nothing seems to be working. I tried implementing a function so that when one of the blocks gets clicked, the others disappear, but so far nothing happens. If someone could please help me I would greatly appreciate it!

HTML:

```
<span id="photos" ng-repeat= "c in colors" >
    <a ng-href = "{{c.link}}" ><img ng-click = "clickFunc()" ng-src="{{c.color}}" /></a>
enter code here
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```js
teamSite.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.colors = [
                  {color: "yellow.png", val: false, link: "#yellow"},
                  {color: "white.jpg", val: false, link: "#white"},
                  {color: "green.png", val: false, link: "#green"},
                  {color: "orange.jpg", val: false, link: "#orange"}
              ];
 $scope.clickFunc = function(c){
 c.val = true;
 for (var x in colors){
  if (x.val == false)
   {
   delete x.color;
   };
 };

});
```

Comment: This can be done by ng-show

Answer (score 2):

Your controller:

```
$scope.colors = [
                 {color: "yellow.png", val: false, link: "#yellow"},
                 {color: "white.jpg", val: false, link: "#white"},
                 {color: "green.png", val: false, link: "#green"},
                 {color: "orange.jpg", val: false, link: "#orange"}
             ];

$scope.clickFunc = function(c){
    $scope.colors[c].val = true;
}
```

your html:

```
<span id="photos" ng-repeat= "c in colors track by $index" >
    <a ng-hide="c.val" ng-href="{{c.link}}"><img ng-click="clickFunc($index)" ng-src="{{c.color}}" />enter code here</a>
</span>
```

First of all you didn't pass anything to your clickFunc then it's quite easy to achieve

Comment: Thank you! But when I implement this code, only the block I clicked disappeared, not the other 3 :( I want the opposite of this to occur

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by ng-show.

```
<span id="photos" ng-repeat= "c in colors" >
<div ng-show="c.val===false"> 
<a ng-href = "{{c.link}}" ><img ng-click = "clickFunc(c)" ng-src="{{c.color}}" /></a> </div>

</span>
```

controller.

```
teamSite.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.colors = [
                 {color: "yellow.png", val: false, link: "#yellow"},
                 {color: "white.jpg", val: false, link: "#white"},
                 {color: "green.png", val: false, link: "#green"},
                 {color: "orange.jpg", val: false, link: "#orange"}
             ];
$scope.clickFunc = function(c){

for (var x in colors){
    x.val=true;
}
 c.val = false;
 }

});
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I implement this code, only the block I clicked disappeared, not the other 3 :( I want the opposite of this to occur

Answer (score 0):

You can ng-hide or filter with ng-repeat

```
 <span id="photos" ng-repeat="c in colors | filter: selectedColor">
   <a ng-href = "{{c.link}}"><span ng-click = "clickFunc(c)" style="background-color:{{c.color}}" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a>
</span>
```

```
$scope.selectedColor = undefined;
  $scope.clickFunc = function(c) {
  console.log(c);
  $scope.selectedColor = c.color;
}
```

Here is [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/walvekarnikhil/ohacay1g/1/) I have changed images to colors.

Comment: @jay-dee not sure if your problem is solved, saw couple of your comments that samples did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller as follows,

```
$scope.colors = [
    {color: "yellow.png", val: false, link: "#yellow"},
    {color: "white.jpg", val: false, link: "#white"},
    {color: "green.png", val: false, link: "#green"},
    {color: "orange.jpg", val: false, link: "#orange"}
];

$scope.clickFunc = function (index) {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.colors.length; i++) {
        // change the value of `val` to true for other colors
        if(i != index) {
            $scope.colors[i].val = true;   
        }
    }
}
```

Add `ng-hide` and `track by $index` phrase in your html as follows,

```
<!-- Add `track by $index` inside `ng-repeat` clause -->
<span id="photos" ng-repeat="c in colors track by $index" >
    <!-- Add `ng-hide` to your tag --> 
    <a ng-hide="c.val" ng-href="{{c.link}}"><img ng-click="clickFunc($index)" ng-src="{{c.color}}">
        enter code here
    </a>
</span>
```

Hope this solves the issue.